# Python - Validate currency

Tags: python

What is the best way to validate an input as a currency (without any currency symbols)
My valid inputs can be only in the form of  40  or 40.12

Comment: what does the raw input data look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about simply using `format()` and try/except for wrong values?

```
>>> "{:.2f}".format(float("40.12"))
'40.12'
>>> "{:.2f}".format(float("40"))
'40.00'
>>> "{:.2f}".format(float("40.123"))
'40.12'
>>> try:
...     "{:.2f}".format(float("40.123€"))
... except ValueError:
...     "fail"
... 
'fail'
```

Note that it simply cuts any number behind the second number behind the decimal point.
You should be more specific by showing us more examples with your desired behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression:

```
re.match(r'\d+(?:[.]\d{2})?$', '40.12')
```

This returns a match object if the input is correct, or `None` if it isn't.

The above regex matches one or more digits optionally followed by a dot and exactly two more digits. This can be tweaked as required if I didn't capture your requirements precisely (the problem statement is somewhat open to interpretation).

Comment: note that this won't work for input like "40.123" - this really depends on your exact requirements, please be more specific how to handle such input by giving more examples with your desired behaviour.

Comment: Two decimal digits makes sense for a US grocery store cash register, but does not make sense for a US gas station, Bitcoins, or stock trading, all of which can have additional decimal places.

Comment: thanks NPE works great.  I modified it slightly. swapped [.] out with \.   and I made it work for 1 or two decimal places. ie: 24.5 or 24.50 `re.match(r'\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$', price)`

Answer (score 0):

I've been googling about an hour for proper way on how to do this. I haven't found any really good and safe way, and wrote regular expression below to match positive non-zero number with optional 1-2 digits after dot-separator:

```
re.match(r'^[1-9]\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$', val)
```

- `^` and `$`: without matching whole string there will be ways to fooling up the regex.
- `[1-9]`: first character always should be from 1 to 9
- `\d*`: after first digit any amount of digits allowed
- `(\.\d{1,2})?`: optional 1-2 digit fraction with dot-separator. Use `[\.\,]` instead of `\.` if multiple separator support is needed